# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, twitter4j

I am having a little trouble with the complier, 
Same code I use on Nexus 5, no error.
as Soon as I use it in Tablet, it crash right away and the error said

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
with brunch of unknown source...

and if i remove

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and remove

```
 compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
```

then it works on both, does anybody know the reason why?
Below is my build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
     multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'
compile 'com.qozix:tileview:2.0.7'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

}
```

Blow is the manifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.package.name" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application
    android:name=".utility.Apps"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".gcm.GcmIntentService" />

    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    and then a lot of activities
```

Comment: keep everything as it is and turn minifyEnabled false

Comment: @Radix I just set the minifyEnabled as false. 
same error. As soon as i exclude twitter4J jar then it is fine. But I need twitter 4j tho.....

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace and your manifest file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I look into my code many time, and I look at each library I am using and I was able to fix it.

First, like @BrainMiz said mutiDexEnabled should set it off. I just comment  it instead of set it as false.

```
defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.package.name"
     minSdkVersion 16
     targetSdkVersion 23
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     //multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Second, it is the dependencies.
Since I don't have any jar in my libs folder I remove

```
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

also remove all not being used gms library, only add the one that being used. I have to give some credits to @Radix because I did found some error in my code regarding to the code that where I check if the device has google play store.

```
dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'
    compile 'com.qozix:tileview:2.0.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should try turning multiDexEnabled false and get rid of the compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0' . You have two play-services which forces you to turn multiDexEnabled to true

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did that because I see the answer from other posts. I just figure it out the way to fix it. I am going to post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
<uses-permission
android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

with this

```
<permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Also i see a lot of anomaly in your manifest with respect to how you have declared GCM . Have a look at the [technical docs.](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.. just clean the project, then make it and finally run it

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the theme of my app in the AndroidManifest.xml file and cleared out my styles.xml file (because I'm a noob and hoped to just use an out-of-the-box android theme). After launching the app, I assume there were zombie references to the old theme that caused the error because, after reverting my changes, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I did remove

```
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and sync project. After added this line and synced again. Next, cleaned project to remove old dex files (may cause problem with dex archives merging), and it helped.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue

Had in gradle.build dependencies :

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

Answer (score -1):

Having same issue and was stuck for a whole day. Finally got solution.

Add in your app level **gradle.build**:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android:multidex:0.1'
}
```

Then override **attachBaseContext** in your **Application** class like below:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

And **don't forgot to enable mutlidex support** as below:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```