# app crash when first run on Android 4.4

Tags: android, exception, firebase

I am using Android studio to build my app
I have 2 emulators the first uses Android 6.0 and the second uses Android 4.4

My app runs perfectly on the Android 6.0 but when I try it on 4.4 it crashes immediately.

I tried debugging the app by putting break point on the first like but it does not reach the first line. it crashes stright away.

The error message I got is not that clear, I dont know what the problem is and how to fix it.

```
01/23 17:26:16: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of D:\__Schlogger\Android\Schlogger\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.asmgx.schlogger.app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.asmgx.schlogger.app/com.asmgx.schlogger.app.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.asmgx.schlogger.app | com.asmgx.schlogger.app.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.asmgx.schlogger.app | com.asmgx.schlogger.app.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.asmgx.schlogger.app | com.asmgx.schlogger.app.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.asmgx.schlogger.app | com.asmgx.schlogger.app.test
Connecting to com.asmgx.schlogger.app
I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8607', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1368)
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 7536 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x000e
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9cd52b20)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.asmgx.schlogger.app, PID: 2822
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzai.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8607', transport: 'socket'
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

After applying the solutions provided, I got another error, and still does not know what does it mean?

```
01-23 03:02:29.954 9105-9105/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
01-23 03:02:29.954 9105-9105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 723: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
01-23 03:02:29.954 9105-9105/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
01-23 03:02:29.964 9105-9105/? E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
                                                     org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportHeight > 0
                                                         at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:720)
                                                         at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:654)
                                                         at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:617)
                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:745)
                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:365)
                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
                                                         at com.asmgx.schlogger.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 03:02:29.964 9105-9105/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-23 03:02:29.964 9105-9105/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9cd52b20)
01-23 03:02:29.974 9105-9105/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 365K, 12% free 3858K/4380K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-23 03:02:29.974 9105-9105/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asmgx.schlogger.app/com.asmgx.schlogger.app.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020054
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020054
                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
                                                        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
                                                        at com.asmgx.schlogger.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2097)
                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700) 
                                                        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525) 
                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74) 
                                                        at com.asmgx.schlogger.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78) 
                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-23 03:02:29.974 9105-9130/? I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:3 and remote module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:8
01-23 03:02:29.974 9105-9130/? I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.tagmanager, version >= 8
01-23 03:02:30.074 9105-9130/? W/GoogleTagManager: No container asset found in /assets/containers. Checking top level /assets directory for container assets.
01-23 03:02:30.194 9105-9130/? W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
01-23 03:02:30.194 9105-9130/? I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 218ms
01-23 03:02:30.194 9105-9130/? D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, timestamp=1485158549979, fatal=1}]
01-23 03:02:30.194 9105-9130/com.asmgx.schlogger.app V/FA: Using measurement service
01-23 03:02:30.204 9105-9130/com.asmgx.schlogger.app V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-23 03:02:30.234 9105-9131/com.asmgx.schlogger.app D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 454K, 14% free 3914K/4528K, paused 7ms, total 10ms
01-23 03:02:30.294 9105-9105/com.asmgx.schlogger.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.asmgx.schlogger.app, PID: 9105
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asmgx.schlogger.app/com.asmgx.schlogger.app.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020054
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020054
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
                                                                           at com.asmgx.schlogger.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
```

Comment: You might be using insta run. Disable insta run from settings and try again.

Comment: I disabled Instant run, yet same errors are still showing. and these errors just for Android 4.4 not Android 6.0

Comment: Are you installing the app directly or installing by generating APK?

Comment: I am running the app from Android Studio

Comment: Did you tried cleaning or restarting Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, same error. there is no problem if I run on Android 6.0... this error shows on Android 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this

**STEP 1:**

Go to your dependency and add this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and in the `defaultConfig` Section add this

```
  defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion xx
        targetSdkVersion xx
        versionCode x

        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Then 
     Create a class called e.g  `MyApp.java`

```
        public class MyApp extends Application{


            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();

            }

            @Override
            protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
                super.attachBaseContext(base);
                MultiDex.install(this);
            }


        }
```

**STEP :2**

Go to your manifest and do the following in the `Application` Tag

```
<application
        android:name="MyApp"
         .
         .
         .
```

Comment: now I get this error VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating

Answer (score 0):

in your gradle, set

**multiDexEnabled true**

and in Application class:

Extend Application class with **MultiDexApplication**

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        MultiDex.install(this);
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }
```

because MultiDexApplication has not been extended so that it can't include gms and any other dex classes so it's giving error at starting of gms String.

You can refer here for more information on how to use multidex :

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: multiDexEnabled is already true in the app and I added attachBaseContext but still same error

Comment: @asmgx - Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34404423/3507492